# bootstrap modal opening when its not supposed to

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a button on my page. Currently it is opening up a bootstrap modal, and i do not want to do that yet. 
My html includes :

```
<div class='bookmarkButtonDiv'>
   <button  type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#newModal' id="IBtn">Bookmark</button>
</div>
```

My Modal Code includes

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal" role="dialog">
<!-- some code to populate the modal -->
```

In my Javascript i have

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function () {
    $('#IBtn').click(function (e) {
      console.log('button clicked'
     });
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

For some reason this is opening up the bootstrap modal, and writing to the console. All i want to do is have it write to the console. Eventually the button will be linked to open the modal, but right now i just want to test things in the console. 
I am using bootstrap 4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `data-toggle='modal' data-target='#newModal'`. Bootstrap automatically attaches event handlers to open the modal when you click an element with those attributes.

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function () {
    $('#IBtn').click(function (e) {
      console.log('button clicked');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='bookmarkButtonDiv'>
  <button  type='button' class="btn btn-primary" id="IBtn">Bookmark</button>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal" role="dialog">
  <h1>Modal contents</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve what you want

**First**

Remove `data-toggle='modal' data-target='#newModal'`

**Second**

```
$('#IBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    console.log('button clicked');
});
```